# python,IF,переменная

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import telebot;
import random;
import time;
from datetime import datetime
from dsb import *
from slovo import *
from intscontol import *

local_date = datetime.now()
lol = (local_date.strftime("%d, %b"))
print(lol)
global pzd
pzd = False

bot = telebot.TeleBot('1611352653:AAF0bktpaDOBpi6p43gk2kPujP9vfjs0iz8');
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text in hi:
        nu = random.randrange(4)
        
        if  nu == 0:
         bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет")
        elif nu == 1:
         bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "хай")  
        elif nu == 2:
         bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Здравствуй")     
        elif nu == 3:
         bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Здравствуйте")

    #######

    if message.text in howareyou:
        nu = random.randrange(3)

        if nu == 0:
         bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "хорошо")
        elif nu == 1:
         bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "шикарно")
        elif nu == 2:
         bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "найс")
        elif nu == 3:
         bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "норм")

    if message.text in dl_on:
      self.pzd = True 
      bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Нижний свет включен")
      print(self.pzd)
      
    if message.text in dl_off:
      self.pzd = False
      bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Нижний свет выключен")
      print(self.pzd)
      
    if message.text == "скажи состояние нижнего света":
      print(self.pzd)
    
    if message.text in temp:
      bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "температура в Одессе сейчас  %s" % W1ThermSensor().get_temperature())

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

получаю UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pzd' referenced before assignment

Comment: Вы смогли перевести текст ошибки? У вас после этого остались вопросы?

Comment: да, но переменная задана в самом начале

Comment: Очевидно при некоторых условиях переменная не объявляется, но используется. Именно об этом вам и сообщает интерпретатор

Comment: как это исправить?

Comment: Объявить переменную __до__ использования)

Comment: она объявлена в самом начале тут отрывок кода вот : global pzd
pzd = False

Comment: Тогда приведите весь относящийся к делу код прямо в вопросе, по кускам невозможно гадать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты делаешь глобальной не существующую переменную. Поменяй инициализацию и присвоение местами.
Вот так не правильно:

```
global pzd
pzd = False
```

Вот так правильно:

```
pzd = False
global pzd
```

А вообще, лучше всего сделать так:

```
def get_text_messages(message):
    pzd = False
```

То есть инициализировать твою переменную внутри функции функции. И работать с ней там, если конечно она тебе не нужна в других функциях. Создавать глобальные переменные не самый лучший вариант.

Answer (score 1):

global pzd нужно объявлять **внутри функции**, у функций свои переменные со своей областью видимости. Что там снаружи объявлено global для функции не указ.

Comment: возможно ли их как-то синхронизировать?

Comment: @DimaBroLach Если объявить её global внутри функции, то это будет одна переменная